# Best way to break down by weeks in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigdata

So what I'm looking to do is create a report that shows how many sales a company had on a weekly basis.

So we have a time field called `created` that looks like this:

```
2016-04-06 20:58:06 UTC
```

This field represents when the sale takes place.

Now lets say I wanted to create a report that gives you how many sales you had on a weekly basis. So the above example will fall into something like `Week of 2016-04-03` (it doesn't have to exactly say that, I'm just going for the simplest way to do this)

Anyone have any advice? I imagine it involves using the `UTEC_TO_xxxxxx` functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [WEEK()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#week) function - it gives you week number

```
SELECT WEEK('2016-04-06 20:58:06 UTC')
```

if you need first day of the week - you can try something like

```
STRFTIME_UTC_USEC((UTC_USEC_TO_WEEK(TIMESTAMP_TO_USEC(TIMESTAMP('2016-05-02 20:58:06 UTC')), 0)),'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 6):

The documentation advises to use standard SQL functions, like [DATE_TRUNC()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions):

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC(DATE '2019-12-25', WEEK) as week;
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to add parentheses:

```sql
SELECT DATE_TRUNC(DATE('2016-04-06 20:58:06 UTC'), WEEK) as week;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is quite an old question and things have moved on since.

In my case, I found that the old `WEEK` function is no longer recognised, so I had to instead use the `EXTRACT` function. The doc for it can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#extract).

For me it was enough to just extract the `ISOWEEK` from the timestamp, which results in the week of the year (the `ISOYEAR`) as a number.

> `ISOWEEK`: Returns the ISO 8601 week number of the `datetime_expression`. `ISOWEEK`s begin on Monday. Return values are in the range [1, 53]. The first `ISOWEEK` of each ISO year begins on the Monday before the first Thursday of the Gregorian calendar year.

So I did this:

```sql
SELECT EXTRACT(ISOWEEK FROM created) as week
```

And if you want to see the week's last day, rather than the week's number in a year, then:

```sql
SELECT last_day(datetime(created), isoweek) as week
```